# I cannot get my asp:Image "Visible" property value to work so that the element is invisible

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to start off by saying that I am **extremely** new to ASP.NET.

I have a piece of ASP.NET code with this line in the Default.aspx file:

```
<asp:Image ID="my_awesome_image" ImageUrl="images/my_awesome_image.png" runat="server" Visible="<%# MyAwesomeImageVisibility %>" />
```

I have this section of code in the Default.aspx.cs file:

```
[System.ComponentModel.Bindable(true)]
public bool MyAwesomeImageVisibility {

    get { return false; }

    set {}
}
```

This is the only code I have for this image, the one line in the `.aspx` file and that section of code in the `.cs` file ... absolutely nothing else regarding this image.

When I run my application, though, the image is still visible, even though I have it returning false.

If I change the Default.aspx file to this:

```
<asp:Image ID="my_awesome_image" ImageUrl="images/my_awesome_image.png" runat="server" Visible="false" />
```

My image is, indeed, hidden.

I will eventually be pulling a value from the database to determine whether or not this image is visible, but for now, I just want to see if I can get the visibility to work from a boolean.

Comment: If `my_awesome_image` is not inside a Repeater, GridView or LisView, put `DataBind()` at the end of Page_load.

Comment: Not to exaggerate things ... but that is awesome! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your code set *visible* property after aspx is translated in html.

As a result, it will add visible="false" to dom element generated by `<asp:Image ... />`  ie `<img ... visible="false" />` .

Here is my suggestion :

in Default.aspx

```
<asp:Image ID="my_awesome_image" ImageUrl="images/my_awesome_image.png" runat="server" />
```

in Default.aspx.cs (for exemple : inside page_load event function) :

```
my_awesome_image.visible = false;
```